# Port 1723 won't close

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I'm not very experienced in linux administration but have been running a server that hosts django for a year or so now. Using ufw I had only opened port 80, 443 and 69 for nginx and SSH.

Recently whilst running tripwire checks I've seen a lot of modifications to files - which I've assumed is just usual system files doing their thing. I also notice port 1723 is open whilst checking with nmap scans from another machine. I can't get it to close even when denying with ufw & iptables.

When I check netstat for listening ports it never lists 1723. Is there something suspicious going on or am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly where have you hosted this server?

Comment: @MichaelHampton a virtual machine with digital ocean

Comment: Hmm. And what was the exact nmap command that you used?

Comment: I did both a syn scan and connection scan, -sS -sT both showed 1723 open

Comment: That doesn't really add up. I would try nmap from a completely different location, just to be sure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the suggestion, I've tried this a couple times and again just now using a ip scanning website and they have always shown it is filtered/closed - wonder why my local machine always shows it open?

Comment: Probably because of your home router. You should reconfigure it.